# How do I convert String data type into integer in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, label, encoder

I have been trying to use machine learning to predict some data but it shows me can not convert str into int error, I even tried label encoder but I am still not able to successfully run the program.

I have tried label encoding

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder



gender_data = pd.read_csv('gender.csv')

le = LabelEncoder()


X = gender_data.drop(columns=['Gender'])
y = gender_data['Gender']
Xv = X.values
yv = y.values

le_encoder_X = le.fit(Xv)
le_encoded_X = le.transform(Xv)


le_encoder_y = le.fit(yv)
le_encoded_y = le.transform(yv)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(le_encoded_X, le_encoded_y, test_size=0.2)



model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     17 yv = y.values
     18 
---> 19 le_encoder_X = le.fit(Xv)
     20 le_encoded_X = le.fit(Xv)
     21

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in fit(self, y)
     93         self : returns an instance of self.
     94         """
---> 95         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
     96         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
     97         return self

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    612         return np.ravel(y)
    613 
--> 614     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    615 
    616

ValueError: bad input shape (66, 4)

Comment: It looks like you missed a step or made a typo, should the `__encoded=` steps be `le.transform()`?

Comment: it was transform earlier but still didn't work

Comment: According to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder), `labelencoder.fit()` takes an "array-like of shape (n_samples,)", but you've passed in multiple columns. In other words, it wants `(66,)` but you've given it `(66,4)`. You need to either use a different encoder or operate on a single column at a time